# Is there a source of deicing holdover time tables?

Tags: ground-operations, deice

Depending on the types of de-ice and anti-ice fluids used, the HOT changes.
Is it possible to post some HOT table here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are interested in. Are you really asking to have a list of all possible tables, and to have it here? If yes, I'm afraid this is too broad for this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some holdover charts I have access to.

[image] 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This FAA document](https://www.faa.gov/other_visit/aviation_industry/airline_operators/airline_safety/media/FAA_2015-16_HoldoverTables.pdf) has a lot of them, starting on page 11.

One example, from [Transport Canada](https://www.tc.gc.ca/eng/civilaviation/publications/tp185-4-08-operations-4049.htm):

[image: Type 4 holdover time graphic]

Comment: Are those times in minutes and seconds? i.e. for "Rain on cold soaked wing" in 27°F weather, the HOT is 10-50 seconds?

Comment: No, hours:minutes.

Comment: That makes more sense, but then it means that at the same temp, one de-icing is good for 12 _hours_ against frost? That seems pretty amazing!